Line labels on a grid
I've created a simple grid by the following piece of code:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A $3 \times 4$ grid} \label{Fig. 1}
\end{figure}
and I want to label the horizontal and vertical lines making up the grid as $h_1, h_2, h_3, h_4$ and $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$, respectively.
I've tried various lines using node and \node, but nothing works. One very simple line of code placed a $h_4$ right in the middle of my grid. I want my labels to be just outside the grid, next to the lines in question. your text
